# Magento can not add new product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

i am creating extension when we enable my extension then the add new product page cant work and give the error in firebuger 'ReferenceError: product_info_tabsJsTabs is not defined'.
my products grid appear in the back end but i add new product they does not show the new product tab. Catalog > Manage Products > Add new Product. Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Have you added any jquery in your extenssion?

Comment: yes i added only javascripts for catalog rule. because i need this. but when i removed or comment this they didn't effected.

Comment: <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>extjs/ext-tree.js</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>extjs/fix-defer.js</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>extjs/ext-tree-checkbox.js</name><params/></action>
               <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/adminhtml/rules.js</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css</name><params/></action>

Comment: the above javascripts i added.

Comment: this all js are already added in core code for product add so there is no need to add this js or css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found my error in our module.
the error in my config.xml i was rewrite the product edit tabs.

```
     <rewrite>
```